# What's wrong with my JavaScript Search Recursive Loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't seem to figure out why my recursive search will not behave recursively.

Do you see what's wrong? Do I have a `haystack[i]` in the wrong place? Because I am not seeing it. I've tried looking through examples on this site but I can't figure out something so simple.

```
search = function(needle, haystack) {

    len = haystack.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (typeof haystack[i] == 'object') {
            search(needle, haystack[i])
        } else {
            if (needle == haystack[i]) {
                console.log('found');
                return;
            }
            console.log('value: ' + haystack[i])
        }
    }
}

var test = [[1], [2], [3,4], [5,6]]
search(4, test)
```

Or see the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/aniyishay/TBMmK/ (Open the Console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `var` in front of `len`, it should be `var len = haystack.length;` otherwise it is treated as a global variable.

when haystack = [[1], [2], [3,4], [5,6]] then len = 4 but again `search(4, [1])` is called then `len = 1` is assinged then when the loop is returned the value of `len = 1` instead of the original 4 because it is a global variable. Now i =2 and len = 1 so the loop exists

Comment: @Doorknob yes it will... did you test it

Comment: Hm. That's interesting, why is that? (+1) Why does changing the global variable to a local one matter?

Comment: @Doorknob After the 1st recursive call, `len` will be set to `1`  (`[1].length`). Returning to the original call, `i < len` will be `false` as `i++` will set `i` to `1` as well, ending that loop and preventing further searching. Scoping `len` allows it to remain set to `4` for the 1st call.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes sense. I couldn't even think of that being the problem, great find thanks so much!